# How to develop a https:// area using mvc2 and IIS 6 on your local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ssl, iis-6

General question to experienced developers:

I want to develop a secure an area on my local machine which I will then roll up to the remote server.

I am using IIS 6 with MVC2 on VS 2008.

I understand that the SSL provider will only issue a certificate to a given domain, which while I find this logical, cannot figure out how to build locally.

How do you guys do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a oddly long and tedious process, but you can create your own certificate and install it on your machine and then use it to develop with SSL running locally.

Michele Leroux Bustamante has the steps listed on several places online, this is just one:

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/security-development/working-with-certificates.aspx

Comment: than ks, that's what i needed to find